# C++: STL multimap.equal_range()

Tags: c++, stl, multimap

I've got this code and I cannot understand part where **equal_range** method returns iterators.
I know range is ***pair*** object with two multimap objects inside, but what I don't get, is why there is  `'for (it = range.first; it != range.second; ++it)'` - What does this mean exactly ?

```
// multmap.cpp -- use a multimap
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

typedef int KeyType;
typedef std::pair<const KeyType, std::string> Pair;
typedef std::multimap<KeyType, std::string> MapCode;

int main()
{
using namespace std;
MapCode codes;
codes.insert(Pair(415, "San Francisco"));
codes.insert(Pair(510, "Oakland"));
codes.insert(Pair(718, "Brooklyn"));
 codes.insert(Pair(718, "Staten Island"));
  codes.insert(Pair(415, "San Rafael"));
  codes.insert(Pair(510, "Berkeley"));

  cout << "Number of cities with area code 415: "
    << codes.count(415) << endl;
  cout << "Number of cities with area code 718: "
    << codes.count(718) << endl;
  cout << "Number of cities with area code 510: "
    << codes.count(510) << endl;
  cout << "Area Code City\n";

  MapCode::iterator it;
  for (it = codes.begin(); it != codes.end(); ++it)
  cout << " " << (*it).first << " "
  << (*it).second << endl;

  pair<MapCode::iterator, MapCode::iterator> range
        = codes.equal_range(718);

  cout << "Cities with area code 718:\n";
  for (it = range.first; it != range.second; ++it) //<------------------ here
  cout << (*it).second << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The iterators in the pair define the range of items with keys equal to what you searched for in the manner `[range.first, range.second)`.

This means that to iterate over that range, you start from `range.first` and advance the iterator until it reaches `range.second`, which means that you have just stepped off the equal range. Conceptually it's the same as what happens when you iterate over a range `[container.begin(), container.end())`.

Comment: I think your answer is the most understandable for me, because It was confusing to see iterating over pair objects members. But if it's *same* as `[container.begin(), container.end())` that's ok. Thanks

Answer (score 33):

The result of `equal_range`, namely your `range` object, is a *pair* of two iterators `[beginning-of-range, end-of-range)`. So you want to iterate over `[range.first, range.second)`:

```
auto range = m.equal_range(4);

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 6 |    =:   m
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
            ^               ^
            |               |
       range.first    range.second
```

Answer (score 4):

`equal_range` returns a pair of iterators `i1, i2` such that all elements within the range `[i1, i2)` have the same key. Hence, in order to iterate through all cities with code 718, you call `equal_range`, and then iterate from the returned pair's `first` to the returned pair's `second`.

Comment: Short and sweet

Answer (score 0):

For loop condition will fail only when provided key in equal_range is not available.
->In below scenario it.first will have (2,20) and it.second also will have (2,20).
-> in case of  mp.equal_range(2)->it.first will have (2,20) and it.second also will have (3,20).

```
> multimap<int, int> m;
> m.insert({ 2, 20 });
> m.insert({ 3, 20 });
> m.insert({ 4, 20 });
> auto it = mp.equal_range(1);
> for (auto itr = it.first; itr != it.second; ++itr) {   //output
> }
> cout << "Out";
```